# post_meta get_the_ID Not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The commands get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'add_price', true); are not working at this function of my wordpress site:

```
function misha_recalculate_price( $cart_object ) {
    var_dump(get_post_type($post_ID));

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;
            foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {
                 $nowprice = $value['data']->get_price(); 
                 $addprice =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'add_price', true);
                 $newprice = $nowprice+$addprice ;
                 $value['data']->set_price( $newprice );         
            }           
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'misha_recalculate_price' );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace the price of the cart item with a custom field value in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375763/replace-the-price-of-the-cart-item-with-a-custom-field-value-in-woocommerce)

Comment: When asking questions on StackOverflow, it's best to include the following:

[  ] What you _want_ to happen

[  ] What _is_ happening that you think is wrong

[X] What you have tried that isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function misha_recalculate_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;
            foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {
                 $nowprice = $value['data']->get_price(); 
                $addprice = get_post_meta($value['data']->get_id(), 'cost_price', true);
                 $newprice = $nowprice+$addprice ;
                 $value['data']->set_price( $newprice );         
            }           
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'misha_recalculate_price', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

can you give it a try this way?

```php
function misha_recalculate_price( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;

        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {
            $nowprice = $value['data']->get_price(); 
            $addprice =  get_post_meta($value['data']->get_id(), 'add_price', true);
            $newprice = $nowprice + $addprice;
            $value['data']->set_price( $newprice );         
        }
    }       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'misha_recalculate_price', 10, 1 );
```